# Modify the value of TextView from an external class

Tags: android, class, android-activity, textview

I have an activity `myActivity` that contains one TextView `myTv`, and another Class `myClass` with a single method `modifyTv`.

How can i modify the value of `myTv` using the `modifyTv` method ?

```
class myActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myClass myc = new myClass();
    myc.modifyTv();// this line of code must be able to modify myTv value.

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

**1.** Pass more info to the constructor. For example, `Context` or `myTv`. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    Context context;
    public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void modifyTv() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.myTv);
        tv.setText("Foobar");
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass(this);
m.modifyTv();
```

**2.** Pass more info to the `modifyTv()` method.

```
public class MyClass {

    public void modifyTv(TextView tv) {
        tv.setText("Foobar");
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.modifyTv((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv));
```

**3.** Other, more complicated ways that don't make much sense.

Comment: don't pass around Activity Contexts on Android, they are destroyed and recreated on rotation and can also cause memory leaks very easily-- http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: @edthethird So the first option isn't recommended?

Comment: no, try to avoid that if possible.  Better to pass the `TextView` itself instead of a `Context`.  Option 2, the same as my answer is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

In 'myClass' you will need a reference to your activity so you can call

```
activity.findViewById(R.id.text_id)
```

You can pass the activity in the constructor or creating let say `setCurrentActivity` method in `myClass`

Or, even easier have a reference to the `TextView` itself.

Comment: by activity do you mean `myActivity` ?

Comment: Exactly ;) But the easiest way will be to pass the TextView as pointed by @edthethird

Answer (score 1):

well,  you could do:

`myc.modifyTv(myTextView);`

and just pass the TextView you want to modify as a parameter.